# Seeking Assistance in Identifying Parameters for Sending DMA ID and Allocated Login ID in NSE's NNF Order Request (C++ Development)

Tags: c++, stock

I am currently developing a gateway in C++ to trade on the National Stock Exchange (NSE) using the NSE's Native Trading Protocol (NNF). I have an alphanumeric DMA ID (Login ID allotted) associated with the client code for authentication purposes. However, I am facing difficulty locating the specific parameter within the latest circular, "TP_FO_Trimmed_NNF_PROTOCOL_9.35," that should be used to include the DMA ID and allocated login ID in the NNF order request.

As a C++ developer, I would greatly appreciate any assistance in identifying the correct parameter(s) required for sending the DMA ID and allocated login ID in the NNF order request. Additionally, if the latest circular does not explicitly mention these parameters, I would be grateful for any alternative approaches or workarounds that could be suggested.

Thank you for your expertise and guidance in resolving this issue.

I am still trying and asked the same query to exchange .

Comment: where do we get that spec without having to pay

Comment: I have the solution for this. There was no need to send any DMA ID in the NNF trimmed request; only the client code is needed to be sent. Thanks.